# Mapeamento Servlet através de anotação @WebServlet não está funcionando

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlet

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento JavaWeb. Estou usando Java versão 11 e Tomcat versão 9.0.
Ao utilizar a anotação `@WebServlet(urlPatterns)` nas classes `OiMundoServlet.java` e `NovaEmpresaServlet.java`, a seguinte mensagem de erro aparece ao chamar as URLs `http://localhost:8080/gerenciador/oi` e `http://localhost:8080/gerenciador/novaEmpresa:`

```
"HTTP Status 404 – Não Encontrado
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/gerenciador/novaEmpresa] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.41"
```

Peço ajuda para conseguir solucionar o problema, fazer com que ao chamar as URLs no browser o conteúdo seja mostrado.

OBS: Quando chamo a url `http://localhost:8080/gerenciador/bem-vindo.html` o conteúdo é perfeitamente mostrado no browser.

Segue abaixo as classes, arquivo `html` e o `web.xml`:

```
package br.com.alura.gerenciador.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/oi")
public class OiMundoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("oi mundo, parabens vc escreveu o primeiro servlets.");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        
        System.out.println("O Servlet OiMundoServlet foi chamado");

    }
}
```

```
package br.com.alura.gerenciador.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/novaEmpresa")
public class NovaEmpresaServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Cadastrando nova empresa");
        
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>Empresa Cadastrada com sucesso!</body></html>");
    }

}
```

bem-vindo.html

```html
<html>

    <body>
    <p>Bem vindos ao curso de Servlets da Alura.</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

web.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="4.0" id="WebApp_ID"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    metadata-complete = "true"
    >

    <display-name>gerenciador</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: olhando assim por cima, percebi que seu método service dentro do empresaservlet não esta anotado com @override, mas deve ter mais coisa por ai...

Comment: Pequeno gafanhoto, fazer um hello world no Tomcat funcionar é um velho clássico de programação Java Web e acrescenta muito aos seus conhecimentos. Em tempos áureos era preciso declarar suas classes servlets associadas aos respectivos URL patterns no arquivo web.xml. Com o advento das Annotations eu não sei se isso ainda é necessário hoje. Dicas: aplicação web rodando como aplicação-raiz do Tomcat é diferente de aplicação não-raiz. Caminho absoluto (http://localhost...) é diferente de relativo (gerenciador/novaEmpresa) que é diferente de absoluto com raiz relativa (/gerenciador...). Boa sorte.

Comment: Veja que em `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/oi")` e `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/novaEmpresa")` você atribuiu ao atributo `urlPatterns` uma *string*. Veja na [documentação](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html#urlPatterns()) que o valor passado para `urlPatterns` deve ser um *array* de *strings*.

Answer (score -4):

Coloque na pesquisa do google javax.servlet.annotation.Webservlet
então irá trazer alguns sites como http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservlet30jar.htm
Nesse, para baixar o jar mostra no manifest uma lista de classes, use a pesquisa do browser para ver se na lista de classes tem Webservlet.class, se tiver, pode usar o jar certo no eclipse ou outra ide.
Para adicionar o jar ao projeto, buildpath, configure buildpath, vá em library, class path, add external jar e selecione o jar baixado, o qual já confirmou que tem Webservlet.class